# How to convert path data to adjacency list

Tags: mysql, ruby, graph, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

I'm setting up a rails "import from csv" task, and I came across departments data (in db) in the form of path. I want it to be adjacency list.

Smth I have:

```
ID, NAME, PATH
---------
1,Valve,000
2,Steam,000.000
3,Sales,000.000.000
4,Developers,000.000.112
7,Designers,000.000.112.000
8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000
9,UI Designers,000.000.112.000.002
10,Web Designers,000.000.112.000.001
11,3D Designers,000.000.112.000.003
12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000
13,Accounting topmanagers,000.000.114.000.000
```

Smth I want:

```
ID, NAME, PATH, PARENT_ID
---------
1,Valve,000, nil
2,Steam,000.000, 1
3,Sales,000.000.000, 2
4,Developers,000.000.112, 2
7,Designers,000.000.112.000, 4
8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000, 7
9,UI Designers,000.000.112.000.002, 7
10,Web Designers,000.000.112.000.001, 7
11,3D Designers,000.000.112.000.003, 7
12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000, 322
13,Accounting topmanagers,000.000.114.000.000, 12
```

Comment: So, you just want to append to each row the ID of the previous row? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: @maxpleaner Problem is the path does not consist of identifiers, only serial numbers.

Comment: Should `'322'` be `'2'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, they're not in Sales (000.000.114 at path) it's another dept.

Comment: Please explain what `'322'` means in terms of the underlying graph.

Comment: How can there be `'12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000'` without a `'xx,yyyy,000.000.114'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's just a sample 13 lines. It's somewhere bellow (13+)

Answer (score 1):

The string appears to describe a directed tree, except the accounting managers,

```
'12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000'
```

seem to have no boss. I've therefore added

```
'14,Accounting big cheese,000.000.114'
```

Here's the data.

```
data =<<-_
ID, NAME, PATH
---------
1,Valve,000
2,Steam,000.000
3,Sales,000.000.000
4,Developers,000.000.112
7,Designers,000.000.112.000
8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000
9,UI Designers,000.000.112.000.002
10,Web Designers,000.000.112.000.001
11,3D Designers,000.000.112.000.003
14,Accounting big cheese,000.000.114
12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000
13,Accounting topmanagers,000.000.114.000.000
_
```

We can use `split("\n")` to convert this string to an array of lines, and then determine the parentage of each node as follows.

```
r1, r2, *rest = data.split("\n")
str = [
  r1,
  r2,
  rest.map do |s|
    parent_match = s[/(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{3}(?=\.\d{3})/]
    parent = arr.find { |ss| parent_match == ss[/(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{3}/] }
    parent.nil? ? "#{s}, nil" : "#{s}, #{ parent[/\d+/] }" 
    end
].join("\n")
```

```
puts str 
ID, NAME, PATH
---------
1,Valve,000, nil
2,Steam,000.000, 1
3,Sales,000.000.000, 2
4,Developers,000.000.112, 2
7,Designers,000.000.112.000, 4
8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000, 7
9,UI Designers,000.000.112.000.002, 7
10,Web Designers,000.000.112.000.001, 7
11,3D Designers,000.000.112.000.003, 7
14,Accounting big cheese,000.000.114, 2
12,Accounting managers,000.000.114.000, 14
13,Accounting topmanagers,000.000.114.000.000, 12
```

In `map`'s block suppose

```
s = '8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000'
```

then

```
parent_match = s[/(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{3}(?=\.\d{3})/]
  #=> "000.000.112.000"
```

`parent_match` is a string of all the triples of digits separated by periods in `s`, other than the last period followed by the last triple of digits. The regular expression reads, "match zero or more groups of 3 digits followed by a period, followed by 3 digits, provided this match is immediately followed by a period and 3 digits (`(?=\.\d{3})`) being a *positive lookahead*).

We then loop through `rest` looking for an element that ends with `parent_match`:

```
parent = rest.find { |ss| parent_match == ss[/(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{3}/] }
  #=> "7,Designers,000.000.112.000"
```

The regex `/(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{3}/` reads, "match zero or more groups of 3 digits followed by a period, followed by 3 digits".

In the next line:

```
parent.nil?
  #=> false
```

so the block returns

```
"#{s}, #{ parent[/\d+/] }" 
  #=> "8,Game Designers,000.000.112.000.000, 7"
```

`parent[/\d+/]` merely extracts the digit character(s) at the beginning of `parent`.

Had I not added the line

```
14,Accounting big cheese,000.000.114
```

the following line (`'12,Accounting ...'`) would have ended, `', nil'`.

Comment: 8,9, 10, 11 have same parent_id as 7. I guess my bad, my data not clear enough.

Comment: I've updated question. Adj. list - just regular hierarchy with id, and parent_id.